# Overriding __bool__ to check if class exists?

Tags: python, software-design

Kind of a design question. I'm initiating a class with an instance variable that will only get its value when the run function is called? Since the data will be the same for all runs I don't want to initialize it over and over again. Should I check if the variable is None or override the **bool** method? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
class Data:
    def __bool__(self):
        return True

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def run_bool(self):
        if not self.data:
            self.data = Data()

    def run_none(self):
        if self.data is None:
            self.data = Data()
```

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. When and why would you call `run_bool` or `run_none`? It seems like an implementation detail leaking out into your interface design.

Comment: python objects are always true in a boolean context unless they define a `__bool__` method or a `__len__` method that return False or 0 respectively for some situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if it's `None`. Defining `__bool__` to always return `True` doesn't do anything, because generic Python objects are truthy anyway, but an explicit `None` check allows for adding genuine `__bool__` behaviour (or switching to a type with such behaviour) later, without breaking things.

It's not clear from your question, but perhaps what you actually want is [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) or [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property).